# pandas GroupBy: How to GroupBy and Aggregate data to show only the top 3 values of a field by count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my first question on StackOverflow so I've tried to be as clear and concise as possible. Many thanks for your patience in advance.

**Background**

I have a dataset of train data with 17 attributes, these include: `origin_station_code`, `origin_station`, `destination_station_code`, `destination_station`, `route_code`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `fleet_number`, `station_code`, `station`, `station_type`, `platform`, `sch_arr_time`, `sch_dep_time`, `act_arr_time`, `act_dep_time`, `date`.

Of these attributes, I am only concerned with: `date`, `origin_station`, `destination_station`, and `start_time`.

This dataset consists of 61 individual CSV files that were combined together to form one DataFrame of just over a million rows using the glob function and a loop.

Each row of the DataFrame represents an individual stop of the train journey. A full route is made of several stops, an example of a route consisting of 19 stops, Sugar Wave to Attempt Pin, is shown in the following screenshot: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBBZy.png).

A new attribute called `complete_route name` has been created by concatenating the `origin_station` and `destination_station` attributes. This can identify all the routes, of which there are 81 unique entries.

**The task**

My task is to subset the DataFrame using pandas such that the dataset shows the 3 most popular routes, per date. This subset DataFrame should show the `date`, the `complete_route name`, and a count of the number times that, that route has taken place each day. The number of unique times a route has taken place can be determined by applying the nunique method to the `start_time` attribute (date/time type).

**My current progress**

Currently, my GroupBy and Aggregate code is able to show how many times each route ran per day, as follows:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(
   ['date', 'complete_route_name']
).agg(
    {
         'start_time': 'nunique'    # count the number of unique routes by using the 'nunique' of the start_times
    }
).reset_index()
```

I now however want to now take my existing code so that it only shows the top 3 unique routes by count, per day, e.g.

```
date           complete_route_name                                   count
2015-08-01     Attempt Pin to Roll Test                              101
               Suit Treatment Turnback to Spiders Toothbrush         93       
               Concourse Village to Port Morris                      87
2015-08-02     Bridge Bottle to Ants Attempt                         119
               North Riverdale to Eastchester                        117
               Wakefield to Kingsbridge                              101

......

2015-09-30     Castleton Corners to Dongan Hills                     121
               Eltingville to Graniteville                           119
               Great Kills to Castleton                              117
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

**Additional resources**

The original dataset and my workbook in its current state can be found hosted on my [GitHub](https://github.com/eddwebster/train) if that is of any use/interest. A static workbook can also be viewed [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/eddwebster/train/blob/master/Train%20Data%20Exploratory%20Data%20Analysis%20Exercise%20using%20pandas%20-%2017012020.ipynb).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_sorted_by_group = df_grouped.groupby(['Date']).apply(
      lambda x: x.sort_values(['Count'],ascending = False)
      ).reset_index(drop = True)

df_grouped_top16 = df_sorted_by_group.groupby(['Date']).head(16)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will continue from where you left

```
df_agg = df.groupby(['date', 'route_name']).agg({'start_time':'nunique'}).reset_index()
```

Then I would do the following to solve for what you asked for

```
df_sorted_by_group = df_agg.groupby(['date']).apply(
      lambda x: x.sort_values(['start_time'],ascending = False)
      ).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Final step

```
df_final = df_sorted_by_group.groupby(['date']).head(3)
```

Example code

```
import pandas as pd
routes = {'route_name': [ 'A to B', 'A to B',  'B to C',   'B to C',   'C to D', 'C to D',  'C to D', 'C to D',  'D to E',
                        'A to Z', 'A to Z',  'B to Z',   'B to Z',   'C to Z', 'C to Z',  'C to Z', 'C to Z',  'D to Z'],
'date': ['01/01/2015','01/01/2015','01/01/2015','01/01/2015','01/01/2015','01/01/2015','01/01/2015','01/01/2015','01/01/2015',
        '02/01/2015','02/01/2015','02/01/2015','02/01/2015','02/01/2015','02/01/2015','02/01/2015','02/01/2015','02/01/2015'],
'start_time': ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10','A11','A12','A13','A14','A15','A16','A17','A18']

         }

df = pd.DataFrame(routes)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format ='%d/%m/%Y')
df

    route_name  date    start_time
0   A to B  2015-01-01  A1
1   A to B  2015-01-01  A2
2   B to C  2015-01-01  A3
3   B to C  2015-01-01  A4
4   C to D  2015-01-01  A5
5   C to D  2015-01-01  A6
6   C to D  2015-01-01  A7
7   C to D  2015-01-01  A8
8   D to E  2015-01-01  A9
9   A to Z  2015-01-02  A10
10  A to Z  2015-01-02  A11
11  B to Z  2015-01-02  A12
12  B to Z  2015-01-02  A13
13  C to Z  2015-01-02  A14
14  C to Z  2015-01-02  A15
15  C to Z  2015-01-02  A16
16  C to Z  2015-01-02  A17
17  D to Z  2015-01-02  A18
```

After applying script from above, you get the following results

```
 df_final
     date   route_name  start_time
0   2015-01-01  C to D  4
1   2015-01-01  A to B  2
2   2015-01-01  B to C  2
4   2015-01-02  C to Z  4
5   2015-01-02  A to Z  2
6   2015-01-02  B to Z  2
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so starting with your working part, I would rewrite it to:

```py
df_grouped = df.groupby(
   ['date', 'complete_route_name'], as_index=False
)['start_time'].nunique()
```

Next IIUC you can do:

```py
df2=df_grouped.groupby("date").rank().le(3)
df_grouped.loc[df2.loc[df2].index]
```